# $G=GL(n,R)$. If $det(tI_n-\frac{1}{2\pi}X)=t^q+E_1(X)t^{q-1}+\dots+E_q(X)$, $\pi:E\to M$ real vector bundle, $\Phi$ curvature, $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=0$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $E\to M$ be a real vector bundle of structural group $G=GL(n,R)$. Denote $I_n$ $n$ by $n$ identity matrix.

"We put $det(tI_n-\frac{1}{2\pi}X)=t^q+E_1(X)t^{q-1}+\dots+E_q(X)$. Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a real vector bundle and $\phi$ be a connection, with curvature for $\Phi$. Then $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=0$..."

Connection $\phi$ gives curvature form $\Phi=d\phi-\frac{1}{2}[\phi,\phi]$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=0$? The book did not defined Pontrjagin class by $E\otimes_RC\to M$'s Chern class. Thus I assume $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=0$ is deduced by some other machinery. Did the book use reduction of structural group to $SO(n)$ instead? In that case then $\Phi=-\Phi^t$. However $E_{2k+1}$ will not detect transpositions as transposition effect is not seen by $det(tI_n-\frac{1}{2\pi}X)$. So $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=E_{2k+1}(-\Phi^t)=-E_{2k+1}(\Phi^t)=-E_{2k+1}(\Phi)$?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Why in particular, $E_{2k}(\Phi)$ is in $H^{4k}(M,R)$? It is not at first sight clear that this is in real coefficient as bundle is not complex. Using $E\otimes_RC\to M$'s Chern class interpretation, I can pick Hermitian metric which pins down a unique connection. What is the alternative option to see this defines a real cohomology without picking metric and using $c_\star(E\otimes_RC)$ interpretation?

Ref. Chern, Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory, Appendix. Sec 2, pg 118.

Comment: You're being sloppy here. First, it's $GL(q,\Bbb R)$. Next, Chern says that $\{E_{2k+1}(\Phi)\} = 0$, not that $E_{2k+1}(\Phi)=0$ itself; the cohomology class is $0$ because the cohomology class doesn't depend on the connection, and we can indeed reduce to the group $O(q)$.)